# How reliable is the weak Fermat-test for base $2$ for large numbers , for example $100$-digit-numbers?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, pseudoprimes

Let $N$ be a $100$-digit odd random number. Suppose , $$2^{N-1}\equiv 1\mod N$$

> How large is approximately the probability that $N$ is composite ?

In other words : How reliable is the weak-fermat-test to base $2$ for large numbers, for example $100$-digit-numbers ?

What we need is the estimation of the number of weak pseudoprimes to base $2$ in the interval $[10^{99},10^{100}]$, but I have no clue how to get such an estimation.

We should get a very small probability that $N$ is composite.

A generalization would be nice to see how fast the probability decreases with increasing number of digits.

I found some data relating to the question here : http://primes.utm.edu/notes/prp_prob.html

The difference to my question is that I do not choose a random base.

Comment: Do you have some nontrivial heuristics so far? I've only done some q&d Pari/GP-code up to $N=10^7$ suggesting that the ratio of number-of-errors and number-of-primes in sequences of intervals decreases when N increases (but this is what you already suggest)

Comment: @DanaJ Hi, do you know a method to determine the smallest fermat-pseudoprime to base $2$ , exceeding, lets say $10^{19}$ ? Brute force seems to be too slow in such ranges, since pseudoprimes with this magnitude seem to be already very rare.

Comment: Probably we start from [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.112.5104&rep=rep1&type=pdf) telling us that for almost all primes, the order of $2$ mod $p$ is large.

Comment: The condition for *weak* Fermat pseudoprimes is $2^{N}\equiv 2\pmod N$. The congruence in your question is valid for Fermat pseudoprimes.

Comment: @Eberhard You seem to have another definition of "weak" in mind. "Strong" pseudoprimes are those passing a refined condition used in the Miller Rabin test. Also , my intent is to not consider the even numbers.

Comment: @Peter I did not say that the definition in your question is for *strong* pseudoprimes but it is not for *weak* ones either. Please see [Fermat_pseudoprime#Weak_pseudoprimes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_pseudoprime#Weak_pseudoprimes)

Comment: I used the deifinition of "weak pseudoprime" I often saw in articles about pseudoprimes. Usually the base is considered to be coprime to the number , probably because the articles mostly dealt with primality testing where the other cases are irrelevant. Considering the "official" definitions , how are the numbers satisfying $2^{N-1}\equiv 1\mod N$ called "officially" ?

Comment: As far as I can tell they are called "Fermat pseudoprime to base 2".